# How to get Timezone from the Lead Address field?

Tags: apex, timezone

How to get timezone abbreviated key from lead address fields using apex?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make a callout to a web service like Google Maps Webservice API, reverse geocode the address, and then submit that lat/lon to a different part of the Google Maps Webservice API to find the timezone.